# About Parallel.For and Lock

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing

```
if (File.Exists(copypath)) File.Delete(copypath);

using (FileStream inputstream = new FileStream(plainpath, FileMode.Open))
{
    using (FileStream outputstream = new FileStream(copypath, FileMode.CreateNew))
    {
        Object lock1 = new Object();
        long inputlength = inputstream.Length;
        Parallel.For((long)0, (long)(inputlength / bufferSize) + ((inputlength%bufferSize)>0?1:0), (i) =>
        {
            byte[] parallelbuff = new byte[bufferSize];
            long cursor = -1;
            lock (lock1)
            {
                cursor = (long)(i * bufferSize);
                inputstream.Seek(cursor, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                read = inputstream.Read(parallelbuff, 0, buff.Length);
            }
            if (read > 0)
            {
                lock (lock1)
                {
                    outputstream.Seek(cursor, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    outputstream.Write(parallelbuff, 0, read);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is a piece of my .NET 4.5 C# code for copying file from 'plainpath' to 'copypath'.

But it doesn't copy some parts of the original file.

Can you tell me about my mistake in it?

Comment: Forget about parallel for a moment. What's wrong with `File.Copy`? Where does the `read` is declared?, there is a threading race with that field. That's obvious.

Comment: This function will be changed as slow-encrypting-function, so I made the function like it. But with Seek and Read be in the same lock, it can have race condition too?

Comment: The locks are going to prevent the threads from acting in parallel.

Comment: For one thing, you ought to split `lock1` into `readLock` and `writeLock`. But it looks like there are might be more problems.

Comment: Those `.Seek()` operations are ususally costly. Will this run on SSDs only?